# Installshield LE is not updating the files while attempting upgrade

Tags: installshield-le

I've spent literally the last 5 hours around this, and can't get it to work.

I've done everything it's said in similar questions.

Change the ProductCode, keep the old UpgradeCode, Change product version.
Again and again. It doesn't replace the updated .exe file it's supposed to.

What am I missing?

Edit: I also have doublechecked the .exe build in visual studio, there it's builded and working properly. Only when I run the setup that's supposed to copy it to install folder, and only then it fails, keeping the old .exe file there, and not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Does the exe on the target system have the same or higher file version than the exe you are installing?  Windows installer will not overwrite a file that has a higher file version then the file it is installing.

look at the install log. search for the component name, check the Request/Action state.  Is the state set to "Local"?  Also search for the file name to see if msiexec tried to copy it.